# how to map eth0 ip address to localhost in apache server ubuntu

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu-12.04

In my Apache server, how to map public ip address to localhost, when i put `eth0` `inet address 10.136.223.141` in browser,it should open localhost

Comment: your question is not clear enough, you want a person from outside to connect to your public ip and then apache should return what would be returned from localhost on some other local server? what do you actually want to do?

Comment: Yes, I want to access this localhost from other systems by public address

Comment: you need to use `mod_proxy`, you can read more about it in here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a virtual host:

https://www.ostechnix.com/configure-apache-virtual-hosts-ubuntu-part-1/